# What's the use of Telegram webhooks?

Tags: node.js, telegram, telegraf

I am using Telegraf library to work with Telegram API in Node.js and set up a webhook. Okay, now every request that was sent to the bot goes to the route. Now i can work with requests, register users, etc. using MVC structure. Ok, but so what? I could just did the same thing using Telegraf middleware like this.

```
bot.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  // do anything you need here
  await next()
})
```

What am i missing? I honestly don't get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as it's stated in the official [documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/webhooks)

> Setting a webhook means you supplying Telegram with a location in the
> form of a URL, on which your bot listens for updates. We need to be
> able to connect and post updates to that URL.

Answer (score 4):

The difference between them:

- **Long-polling:** the bot always asks Telegram API for updates (hence the name).
- **Webhook:** Telegram send a POST request to the endpoint you set whenever the bot got update.